# Is it save to run a mongodb replica set with 3 containers in production on the same server?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am currently trying to get mongodb transactions working in our project.
We currently have only have one server.

Is it a good idea to run 3 containers for a replica set on the same server?
Or would it be better to run only one container as a single member replica set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no benefit to running multiple MongoDB nodes on the same server, and there are severe downsides.

The point of a replica set is to provided redundancy, for example in the case of a hardware or networking failure. But if all three nodes are on the same server, then any such failure will affect all three at once - so this setup will fail to provide any redundancy.

The downsides: multiple MongoDB instances on the same server will run into memory conflicts, leading to performance problems.

If you want to use transactions, then you can set up a replica set with **just one member**. You don't get any benefits of redundancy or availability, but it will let you get started with transactions.